# Haskell fibonacci list with Integral typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass, fibonacci

If I load the following list in GHCi the list is computed slowly, until the program eventually closes just after computing 3524578, the 33rd item in the list.

```
fibonacci :: (Integral a) => [a]
fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
```

If I remove the first line and load the following instead the list is computed very quickly and GHCi doesn't close.

```
fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
```

Why is the polymorphic list so much slower than the `Integer` list? Why does GHCi close?

Comment: Have you checked what type haskell thinks this is? (i.e. without the first line do `:t fibonacci`) Was it what you expected?

Comment: use `:t fibonacci` in gchi. It's be `fibonacci :: [Integer]`

Comment: The first `fibonacci` is polymorphic. See [Memoizing polymorphic functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization#Memoizing_polymorphic_functions).

Comment: I get that the first is polymorphic and the second is [Integer] but not why one is so much slower than the other.

Comment: @huitlarc Your first problem is that you're trying to profile something in GHCi.  Compile with `-O2` and run with `+RTS -s -RTS`, then see if there's an actual difference.  Also, my guess is that the reason the polymorphic list is slower is because GHCi has to make more decisions at runtime about the types of the elements and can't optimize it more.

Comment: I have just noticed that if you run the polymorhic list for long enough GHCi closes.

Comment: The polymorphism prevents memoization. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized/11466959#11466959.

Answer (score 3):

With your first version, while it looks like a value, you actually write a function (a function on a lower level than Haskell itself).

To understand this, think about the following code that would be possible with your definition:

```
main = println (fibonacci !! 17 :: Int, fibonacci !! 19 :: Integer)
```

Of course, the 17 and 19 are completly arbitrary. The point is that the first tuple element requires to compute fibonacci as a list of `Int`, while the second assumes it is a list of `Integers`. As you probably know, there is no such list in Haskell that is halfway `Int`and `Integer` - a list is either `[Int]` or `[Integer]` (or something completely different).

Because this is so, we can conclude on pure logical grounds, without having deep knowledge of Haskell's run time system, that `fibonacci` is *neither* a list of `Int` nor a list of `Integer` nor a list of something else - it is just a recipe to build such a list on request.

That being said, as long as you do something like:

```
take 10 fibonacci
```

it should not matter that much (fibonacci is just computed once up to 10 elements).

But when you say

```
map (fibonacci !!) [1..10]
```

chances are that fibonacci is recomputed for every index. Clearly, the higher the indexes go, the longer this will take.

Comment: `take 35 fibonacci` in the first case is very slow and causes GHCi to close. It is almost instantaneous in the second.

Comment: While there's an argument that it shouldn't matter, in GHC (without optimisaton) it does. Since you keep recursively calling the same polymorphic function, without memoization or cse, you'll get exponential performance. You can help ghc out by enclosing the body of your function in a let though, like so `fib = let helper = funcbody in helper`

Answer (score 1):

This seemed suspicious, so I did a little bit of investigation. 
First I made two modules:

```
-- fib0.hs
fibonacci :: (Integral a) => [a]
fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
main = print $ take 10000 $ fibonacci

-- fib1.hs
main = print $ take 10000 $ fibonacci
fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibonacci (tail fibonacci)
```

Then compiled as follows: `ghc -O2 -prof -auto-all fib0.hs & ghc -O2 -prof -auto-all fib1.hs` (Note: `&` is for Windows, *nix uses `;` to seperate multiple commands on a line). And ran them with `fib0 +RTS -p & fib1 +RTS -p`. This will run both fibs and the flags `+RTS -p` produce a file name fib0/1.prof, which contains runtime information about your program. Doing this, I saw that they both took the exact same amount of time! (0.70s to be precise - it may take longer on your machine, if you can't stand waiting that long, then decrease the 10000 elements).

You'll notice I compiled with `-O2`. This sets optimization to 'level' 2. There are three levels - 0,1, and 2. GHCi by default uses `O0`. So then I tried `ghc -O0 -prof -auto-all fib0.hs & ghc -O0 -prof -auto-all fib1.hs` (ghc would default to `-O1`, so you must manually set level 0). Wouldn't you know it, when I ran them, fib0 crashes with out of memory exception and fib0 completes just fine (albiet very slowly. I had to decrease `take 10000` to `take 100` - but this is obviously to be expected).

This would be a normal behaviour. Optimization removes bad programming mistakes - like manually enforcing polymorphism when it is beneficial to use a single type - don't do this unless you must!

If you would like to know more, you can try `ghc -O0 -f-ext-core fib0.hs & ghc -O0 -f-ext-core fib1.hs`. This will generate 'core' files for both programs. Core is the last stage of GHC compilation before you start making object files. It generates plain-text .hcr files. These may be very hard to read, so let me highlight some key points for you.

fib0.hcr contains the following:

```
...
base:GHCziNum.fromInteger @ ac zddNumazzzz
...
```

Basically, you call `fromInteger` on every single number, starting with 0 and 1, in your sequence. Why do this? You have told it, "the type of fibonacci must be *any* numeric type". It creates 0 and 1 as `Integer`s and then uses `fromInteger` to create values of type `Num a => a` (This is the only way to create polymorphic literals) . All of these calls to `fromInteger` build up *very* expensive thunks - so you get out of memory exception.

Take a look at fib1.hcr. Nowhere does it contain `fromInteger`. Leaving GHC to infer the type of fibonacci lets it just use `Integer`, which means no thunks.

Why does optimizing remove this problem? GHC notices that you only use fibonacci to print the numbers. You don't need this polymorphism. So it optimizes it away! 
Note that it also does other things that make fibonacci much, much faster, like inlining.

Comment: The `fromInteger` calls wouldn't create that amount of slowdown. Like nymk said, it's a loss of memoization. Consider
  
`fib = let fibm = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibm (tail fibm) in fibm`