# Haskell: Why does this work -- an example of memoization?

Tags: haskell, dynamic-programming, lazy-evaluation, memoization

Hi I am looking at this example from [Memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization):

```
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
    where fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
```

I am just wondering why this even work, since for me if you call `memoized_fib(n-2)` then you are "creating" a new list and doing things with it and after your return from it the list containing partial result would be gone? So `memorized_fib(n-1)` won't benefit from it at all?

Comment: The memoization breaks the way you are thinking of if you change the definition to `memoized_fib n = map fib [0 ..] !! n`. I don't know shy but maybe someone else can shed some light on it.

Comment: http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/04/the-haskell-heap/ is a great series about the haskell heap, it might also explain this (not sure), but even if not it's a good read!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`memoized_fib` is a [CAF](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Constant_applicative_form), which is as good as a literal constant in avoiding creation of new stuff. No variables ⇒ no things to bind new stuff to ⇒ no creation of new stuff (in simplified terms).

Comment: So does it mean that there will be only one ```memized_fib``` instance ? How do I tell whether a function is a CAF or not? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, only one. You check it against the definition in the linked article ;)

Comment: Thanks first, and I mean no offence but the problem here is that after I click into the link I found that I do not know anything about Super combinator and after clicking into it I found I do not know what is a Combinator, and then it is defined as "A function with no free variables", free variables? never heard of it. Probably I missed the most important thing before learning Haskell, i.e. learn lambda calculus and category theory first!

Comment: Yes, a bit of lambda calculus and category theory won't hurt!

Comment: @dorafmon: Lambda calculus definitely. It’s the core of modern functional languages. Category theory on the other hand is only necessary if you want to write or understand the internals of libraries that take advantage of results from category theory.

Answer (score 8):

I can explain missingno's observation, and it may help you understand the behaviour you are seeing.  It's important to understand what the `where` clause desugars to.

The code you presented is

```
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
    where fib = ...
```

which desugars to

```
memoized_fib = let fib = ...
               in \n -> map fib [0 ..] !! n
```

missingno presented the following, which looks like a simple eta expansion, but it's not!

```
memoized_fib n = map fib [0 ..] !! n
    where fib = ...
```

desugars to

```
memoized_fib = \n -> let fib = ...
                     in map fib [0 ..] !! n
```

In the former case you can see that the `fib` structure is shared between invocations of `memoized_fib` whereas in the latter case`fib` is reconstructed each time.

Comment: In the first case where you say that `fib` is shared. Why is it shared? Are you saying `memoized_fib = let fib = ...` doesn't redeclare the `fib` when it's called again? It reuses the prior `fib`? Does that mean it's equivalent to having the `fib` defined outside the `memoized_fib` function?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent to defining `fib` outside `memoized_fib`.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you show depends on a given compiler's behaviour. Here's the desugaring like Tom Ellis suggested:

```
memoized_fib = 
    let   fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
    in
       (map fib [0 ..] !!)
```

Nothing guarantees that the list `map fib [0..]` will be reused, i.e. *"shared"*. Especially when you omit the type signature, like I did, making this a polymorphic definition.

Better make that list explicit, giving it a name:

```
memoized_fib n = 
    let   fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = g (n-2) + g (n-1)
          g = (fibs !!)
          fibs = map fib [0 ..]
    in
       g n
```

This was [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized/11466959#11466959).