# does this Elm Fibonacci example need to be memoized?

Tags: dynamic-programming, elm, memoization

Here is the Fibonacci code on the Elm syntax page.  Just curious does recursion need to be memoized or does lazy evaluation take care of it?

```
fib n = case n of
  0 -> 1
  1 -> 1
  _ -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

In other languages (such as Python) the number of function calls would grow exponentially in `n` so that in if `f(30)` would compute `f(10)` like 4000 times or someting.

- Haskell [How is this fibonacci-function memoized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized)
- Python [What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: "does lazy evaluation take care of it" <- Elm doesn't have lazy evaluation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viewing the compiled source (as of Elm 0.18), you'll see that the Elm code gets transpiled down to the following javascript code (the variable names may differ).

```js
var _user$project$Temp1483721371847322$fib = function (n) {
    var _p0 = n;
    switch (_p0) {
        case 0:
            return 1;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        default:
            return _user$project$Temp1483721371847322$fib(n - 1) + _user$project$Temp1483721371847322$fib(n - 2);
    }
};
```

Javascript does no automatic memoization since function calls are not guaranteed to be deterministic. If you require memoization, you will have to roll your own.

Comment: ah!  thank you!  As usual Elm maps to JavaScript which as none of this nice optimizations other languages have.