# Fibonacci infinite list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, fibonacci

I want to create a list of Fibonacci numbers.
I want to call fib x and it should give me a list till the xth element.
How do I achieve that.

I would calculate fib numbers like this:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

How do I put the result in a list to call the list till the element I need?

Comment: The above is not an efficient implementation, it will run in exponential time.

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466284/how-is-this-fibonacci-function-memoized).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A compact definition (that scales linear) is the following:

```
fib :: Num n => [n]
fib = 0 : nxt
    where nxt = 1 : zipWith (+) fib nxt

fibN :: Num n => Int -> [n]
fibN = flip take fib
```

What we here do is constructing a list `fib` that is "cons" of `0` and `nxt` (the rest of the lists). `nxt` is defined in the `where` clause as a "cons" of 1 and and the result of `zipWith (+) fib nxt`. The `zipWith` elementwise adds the elements of `fib` and `nxt` together, since `nxt` is always one element "ahead" of `fib`, we thus add the two last elements together. We then `take` the first `n` elements in the `fibN` function.

So we obtain a list like:

```
   fib          nxt
    |            |
    v            v
+-------+    +-------+    +-------------+
|  (:)  | ,->|  (:)  | ,->|   zipWith   |
+---+---+ |  +---+---+ |  +-----+---+---+
| 0 | o---'  | 1 | o---'  | (+) | o | o |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +-----+-|-+-|-+
  ^            ^                  |   |
  |            `------------------|---'
  `-------------------------------'
```

In case we thus evaluate up to the third element, this means that we call `zipWith`, and this will produce the sum of the head of `fib` and `nxt` and advance both points, like:

```
   fib          nxt
    |            |
    v            v
+-------+    +-------+    +-------+    +-------------+
|  (:)  | ,->|  (:)  | ,->|  (:)  | ,->|   zipWith   |
+---+---+ |  +---+---+ |  +---+---+ |  +-----+---+---+
| 0 | o---'  | 1 | o---'  | 1 | o---'  | (+) | o | o |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +-----+-|-+-|-+
               ^            ^                  |   |
               |            `------------------|---'
               `-------------------------------'
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your example. The graphic is also a very good help. I ask myself how did you do that graphic? :D Do you have a program to help you create such kind of graphics or did you do it yourself?

Comment: @CoreNoob: I write the ascii art myself :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a fast way (because your function runs in exponential time), but using your function `fib`

```
nfibs :: Int -> [Integer]
nfibs n = take n (map fib [0..])
```

Comment: You can drop the `Int ->` part of the signature :)

Comment: No, I just forgot to include it on the LHS (he wants up to the nth element)

Comment: `take` + an infinite list is very modular, but when it's this local, I'd just do the rewrite to `map fib [0..n-1]`, personally.

Comment: You're right, but I think this has more utility as a pedagogical example. Perhaps moving `map fib [0..]` to a `where` clause would have made that clearer?