# How does haskell manage memory of recursive function calls

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, memoization

I have been working on a problem that benefits a lot from catching results of my functions and in my research I came across [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization) article. I am stunned at how simple is the core in "Memoization with recursion" section namely:

```
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0 ..] !!)
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = memoized_fib (n-2) + memoized_fib (n-1)
```

I feel like I understand **how** it work but do correct me if I'm wrong - this function saves a list which is populated using same function.

What bothers me is that I don't understand **why** this works, originally I was under impression that once haskell evaluates a function it releases memory that was used to store variables inside this function, but here it seems that if part of the list was evaluated by one call of this function those values are still available to another call of the same function.

Just typing this up makes my head hurt, because I don't understand why value used in calculation of `fib 2` should be available in calculation of `fib 3` or better yest `fib 100`?

My gut feeling tells me that this behavior has two problems(I'm probably wrong but again not sure why):

- purity of this function we are evaluating one call using variable that did not arrive from parameters of this function
- memory leaks no longer sure when will haskell release memory from this list

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to understand if you compare your definition to this:

```
not_memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
not_memoized_fib m = map fib [0 ..] !! m
   where fib 0 = 0
         fib 1 = 1
         fib n = not_memoized_fib (n-2) + not_memoized_fib (n-1)
```

The definition above is essentially the same as yours, except that it takes an explicit argument `m`. It is a so-called eta-expansion of the previous function, and is *semantically* equivalent to it. Yet, operationally, this has drastically worse performance, since memoization here does not take place.

Why? Well, your function defines the list `map fib [0..]` *before* taking the (implicit) input parameter `m`, so there is only one list around, for all `m` we may pass later on as arguments. Instead, in `not_memoized_fib` we first take `m` as input, and then define the list, making the function create a list for every call to `not_memoized_fib`, destroying performance.

It is even easier to see if we use `let` and lambdas instead of `where`. Compare

```
memoized :: Int -> Integer
memoized = let
   list = map fib [0..]
   fib 0 = 0
   fib 1 = 1
   fib n = memoized (n-1) + memoized (n-2)
   in \m -> list !! m
   -- ^^ here we take m, after everything is defined,
```

with its *let over lambda <sup>(*)</sup>* code structure, to

```
not_memoized :: Int -> Integer
not_memoized = \m -> let
            -- ^^ here we take m, before everything is defined, so
            -- we define local bindings {list,fib} at every call
   list = map fib [0..]
   fib 0 = 0
   fib 1 = 1
   fib n = not_memoized (n-1) + not_memoized (n-2)
   in list !! m
```

with the let *inside* the lambda.

In the former case, there is only one list around, while in the latter there is one list for each call.

---

<sub><sup>(*)</sup> a *searchable* term.</sub>

Comment: BTW, [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466959/849891), older GHC with -O2 would compile even the `not_memoized_fib` as a memoizing one. do we know for sure what the more current versions do? perhaps this is related to the CSE changes...

Comment: With GHC 8.6.4 and `-O2`, both `memoized_fib` and `not_memoized_fib` are equally fast.  Switching to `last $ map fib [0..m]` makes it (extremely) slow.

Answer (score 1):

The list defined by `map fib [0..]` is defined as part of the *definition* of the function, rather than being created each time the function is called. Due to laziness, though, the list is only "realized" as necessary for any given call.

Say your first call is `memoized_fib 10`. This will cause the first 10 Fibonacci numbers to actually be computed and stored in memory, and they will stay in memory for the duration of the program. Subsequent calls with a smaller argument don't need to compute anything; subsequent calls with larger arguments need only compute those elements that occur later in the list than the largest existing element.