# How to solve correctly pascal triangle in haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pascals-triangle

I am implementing Pascal Triangle in Haskell, but the code is not working the right way. The code is giving 1 more row. Also I've trying to print the result like a tree but it's been difficult and confuse for me, so I did not add the printing code.

These are the results I get:

```
*Main> pascal 1
[[1],[1,1]]
*Main> pascal 2
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1]]
```

Expected output:

```
*Main> pascal 2
    [[1],[1,1]]
```

Ideal output:

```
*Main> pascal 3
           
         1  
        1 1 
       1 2 1
```

This is the code:

```
choose n 0 = 1
choose 0 k = 0
choose n k = choose (n-1) (k-1)* n `div` k

pascal :: Integer -> [[Integer]]
pascal 0 = [[1]]
pascal m = pascal (m - 1) ++ [[choose m k | k <- [0,1..m]]]
```

Comment: So...  is your expected output for `pascal 1` going to be `[[1]]`?  If so, isn't this just a matter of having the wrong base case?

Comment: @Carl It's an easy thing to test whether simply fixing the base case produces a function that matches the expected output given. Did you try that test?

Comment: I asked a question on memoization of pascals triangle in haskell, might give some inspiration perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473130/memoization-pascals-triangle

Comment: edits must not invalidate existing answers. I rolled it back to 1st version, with small edit to title.

Comment: I guess, the post is left at what it is. I asked a [question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352989/edit-wars-with-new-users) about edit wars, inspired by this one. If the OP wants, I shall remove links to this SO post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let me note that your approach is a bit backwards. The whole point of Pascal's triangle is that it offers an efficient way to tabulate the `choose` function *without* calculating each of the values independently. That doesn't mean your way of doing it is *wrong*, but it's certainly not very good. Do try to solve the problem without the `choose` function! You know,

```
                 1
                ╱ ╲
               1   1
              ╱ ╲+╱ ╲
             1   2   1
            ╱ ╲+╱ ╲+╱ ╲
           1   3   3   1
          ╱ ╲+╱ ╲+╱ ╲+╱ ╲
         1   4   6   4   1
        ...     ...     ...
```

Hint: don't start with writing a function that computes the entire triangle or individual elements, but rather one that takes one *row* of the triangle and gives you the next row. Then all that's left to do is [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate)ing that function.

As for how to fix it in your current approach – well, obviously if you want `pascal 1` to yield `[[1]]` then `pascal 0 = [[1]]` can't be a very sensible base case. Rather, *start* with

```
pascal 1 = [[1]]
```

or

```
pascal 0 = []
```

(which is a little better because the function will not be undefined for zero... but still is for negative numbers – we like to avoid this or at least give a clear error message for such situations.)

Then, for the `m`th line, you should compute only the `choose (m-1) k` series. Easy to fix. Remember to also pick the correct range for `k`.

As for how to pretty-print the output in a nice isosceles shape: write a helper function

```
centerAlign :: [String] -> [String]
```

which adds whitespace in front of each line, corresponding to half of what it lacks in [`length`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) compared to the [`maximum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:maximum)-`length` one.

Then you can simply do `putStrLn . unlines . centerAlign . map show` on the Pascal's triangles.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to get the "ideal output":

```
printPascal :: [[Integer]] -> IO ()
printPascal pasc = 
  let                      
     process row = 
      let 
       striped = (foldr1 (\ x y -> x ++ " " ++ y) . map show) row
       spaces = replicate ((n - length striped) `div` 2) ' '
      in spaces ++ striped ++ "\n"
                   
     n = length . (foldr1 (\ x y -> x ++ " " ++ y) . map show) . last $ pasc
  in mapM_ (putStr . process) pasc
```

First of all, here are some samples (the latter one does not look great, truth be told - see **Edit** for a better version):

```
GHCi> printPascal (pascal 1)
1
GHCi> printPascal (pascal 4)
   1   
  1 1  
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1  
GHCi> printPascal (pascal 8)
         1         
        1 1        
       1 2 1       
      1 3 3 1      
     1 4 6 4 1     
   1 5 10 10 5 1   
 1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
```

So, what is happening here:

1. We take an already built triangle `pasc`. We turn the last row into a string, putting all the elements in a string, separated by spaces. That's the length of each row in our final triangle.
2. We take each row and process it with `process`. It does a simple thing: it puts all the elements in a string, separated by spaces. If its length is less then `n`, it adds the missing spaces (equal amount on both right and left; in fact, the spaces on the right might be dropped, as it is done). At the end we put a new line.
3. We map `putStr . process` over the list and then sequence the effects. `mapM` (or its more general version - `traverse`) serves for such purposes. The resulting type would have been `IO [()]` - we do not need a list of units, so we make it `IO ()` by replacing `mapM` with `mapM_` (or its more general version - `traverse_`).

You might want to combine `pascal` and `printPascal`:

```
buildAndPrintPascal :: Integer -> IO ()
buildAndPrintPascal = printPascal . pascal
```

---

**Edit:** to make the tree look a bit nicer for bigger numbers we might want to change the step (keeping it odd). Here is the edited version of the code, the only edit is the `step`:

```
printPascal :: [[Integer]] -> IO ()
printPascal pasc = 
  let                      
     process row = 
      let 
       striped = (foldr1 (\ x y -> x ++ step ++ y) . map show) row
       spaces = replicate ((n - length striped) `div` 2) ' '
      in spaces ++ striped ++ "\n"
                   
     n = length . (foldr1 (\ x y -> x ++ step ++ y) . map show) . last $ pasc
     step = 
       let 
        times = (floor . logBase 10 . fromInteger . maximum . last $ pasc) * 2 + 1
       in replicate times ' '
  in mapM_ (putStr . process) pasc
```

Here are some samples:

```
GHCi> buildAndPrintPascal 4
   1   
  1 1  
 1 2 1 
1 3 3 1
GHCi> buildAndPrintPascal 8
                1                
              1   1              
            1   2   1            
          1   3   3   1          
        1   4   6   4   1        
     1   5   10   10   5   1     
  1   6   15   20   15   6   1  
1   7   21   35   35   21   7   1
GHCi> buildAndPrintPascal 10
                               1                               
                            1     1                            
                         1     2     1                         
                      1     3     3     1                      
                   1     4     6     4     1                   
               1     5     10     10     5     1               
           1     6     15     20     15     6     1           
        1     7     21     35     35     21     7     1        
    1     8     28     56     70     56     28     8     1    
1     9     36     84     126     126     84     36     9     1
```

I reckon them to look a bit nicer.